# How to write loop for time and give a number

Tags: r, loops, time

I have a measurement in every 10-second interval with a date and I need to put a continuous number in one column for the time.  Could you please help me to create a loop in R. example data:

```
MeasureDateTime  CO2    H2O

01/03/2021 19:25:57  553    0.6

01/03/2021 19:26:07  553    0.6

01/03/2021 19:26:17  553    0.6

01/03/2021 19:26:27  554    0.6

01/03/2021 20:26:00  556    0.6

01/03/2021 20:26:10  558    0.6

01/03/2021 20:26:20  568    0.6

01/03/2021 20:27:42  584    0.6

01/03/2021 19:27:52  595    0.6

01/03/2021 19:28:02  598    0.6

01/03/2021 19:28:12  599    0.6

01/03/2021 19:28:22  598    0.6
```

Example how I want

```
MeasureDateTime  CO2     H2O  RecordNo

01/03/2021 19:25:57  553    0.6  1

01/03/2021 19:26:07  553    0.6  2

01/03/2021 19:26:17  553    0.6  3

01/03/2021 19:26:27  554    0.6  4

01/03/2021 20:26:00  556    0.6  1

01/03/2021 20:26:10  558    0.6  2

01/03/2021 20:26:20  568    0.6  3

01/03/2021 20:27:42  584    0.6  1

01/03/2021 19:27:52  595    0.6  2

01/03/2021 19:28:02  598    0.6  3

01/03/2021 19:28:12  599    0.6  4

01/03/2021 19:28:22  598    0.6  5
```

Comment: Hi Rajan, shouldn't 8th and 9th row both be `1`?

Comment: yes, it should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that actually it works in scenario as per comments

```r
df <- read.table(text = "MeasureDateTime  CO2    H2O
'01/03/2021 19:25:57'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:07'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:17'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:27'  554    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:00'  556    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:10'  558    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:20'  568    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:27:42'  584    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:27:52'  595    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:02'  598    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:12'  599    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:22'  598    0.6
'25/03/2021 23:59:43'  567    0.5
'25/03/2021 23:59:53'  567    0.5
'26/03/2021 00:00:03'  567    0.5
'26/03/2021 00:00:13'  567    0.5
                 ", header = T)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(MeasureDateTime = as.POSIXct(MeasureDateTime, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')) %>%
  group_by(d = cumsum(c(0,diff.difftime(MeasureDateTime)) != 10)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-d)
#> # A tibble: 16 x 4
#>    MeasureDateTime       CO2   H2O    id
#>    <dttm>              <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 2021-03-01 19:25:57   553   0.6     1
#>  2 2021-03-01 19:26:07   553   0.6     2
#>  3 2021-03-01 19:26:17   553   0.6     3
#>  4 2021-03-01 19:26:27   554   0.6     4
#>  5 2021-03-01 20:26:00   556   0.6     1
#>  6 2021-03-01 20:26:10   558   0.6     2
#>  7 2021-03-01 20:26:20   568   0.6     3
#>  8 2021-03-01 20:27:42   584   0.6     1
#>  9 2021-03-01 19:27:52   595   0.6     1
#> 10 2021-03-01 19:28:02   598   0.6     2
#> 11 2021-03-01 19:28:12   599   0.6     3
#> 12 2021-03-01 19:28:22   598   0.6     4
#> 13 2021-03-25 23:59:43   567   0.5     1
#> 14 2021-03-25 23:59:53   567   0.5     2
#> 15 2021-03-26 00:00:03   567   0.5     3
#> 16 2021-03-26 00:00:13   567   0.5     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Alternate answer using only `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(MeasureDateTime = as.POSIXct(MeasureDateTime, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')) %>%
  group_by(d = cumsum(c(0,diff.difftime(MeasureDateTime)) != 10)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-d)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    MeasureDateTime       CO2   H2O    id
#>    <dttm>              <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 2021-03-01 19:25:57   553   0.6     1
#>  2 2021-03-01 19:26:07   553   0.6     2
#>  3 2021-03-01 19:26:17   553   0.6     3
#>  4 2021-03-01 19:26:27   554   0.6     4
#>  5 2021-03-01 20:26:00   556   0.6     1
#>  6 2021-03-01 20:26:10   558   0.6     2
#>  7 2021-03-01 20:26:20   568   0.6     3
#>  8 2021-03-01 20:27:42   584   0.6     1
#>  9 2021-03-01 19:27:52   595   0.6     1
#> 10 2021-03-01 19:28:02   598   0.6     2
#> 11 2021-03-01 19:28:12   599   0.6     3
#> 12 2021-03-01 19:28:22   598   0.6     4
```

---

Earlier Answer using `purrr`

```r
df <- read.table(text = "MeasureDateTime  CO2    H2O
'01/03/2021 19:25:57'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:07'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:17'  553    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:26:27'  554    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:00'  556    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:10'  558    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:26:20'  568    0.6
'01/03/2021 20:27:42'  584    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:27:52'  595    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:02'  598    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:12'  599    0.6
'01/03/2021 19:28:22'  598    0.6", header = T)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(MeasureDateTime = as.POSIXct(MeasureDateTime, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')) %>%
  mutate(id = +(c(0,diff.difftime(MeasureDateTime)) != 10)) %>%
  mutate(id = accumulate(id, ~ifelse(.y == 0, .x + 1, 1)))
#>        MeasureDateTime CO2 H2O id
#> 1  2021-03-01 19:25:57 553 0.6  1
#> 2  2021-03-01 19:26:07 553 0.6  2
#> 3  2021-03-01 19:26:17 553 0.6  3
#> 4  2021-03-01 19:26:27 554 0.6  4
#> 5  2021-03-01 20:26:00 556 0.6  1
#> 6  2021-03-01 20:26:10 558 0.6  2
#> 7  2021-03-01 20:26:20 568 0.6  3
#> 8  2021-03-01 20:27:42 584 0.6  1
#> 9  2021-03-01 19:27:52 595 0.6  1
#> 10 2021-03-01 19:28:02 598 0.6  2
#> 11 2021-03-01 19:28:12 599 0.6  3
#> 12 2021-03-01 19:28:22 598 0.6  4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: the code is working with the example data set, but when I use real data it is only producing 1 in each row.

Comment: Yes, it worked but, now I have a new problem.

Comment: Yes, it worked but, now I have a new problem. When the hour changes the count starts again, but actually it needs to be continuous. example :

measurementdataetime  id

2021-03-25 23:59:43  1

2021-03-25 23:59:53  2

2021-03-26 00:00:13  1

2021-03-26 00:00:23  2

Example: How I want: 

measurementdataetime  id

2021-03-25 23:59:43  1

2021-03-25 23:59:53  2

2021-03-26 00:00:13  3

2021-03-26 00:00:23  4

Comment: See that it still works.  In case any further clarification is needed You should mark this one as accepted and post the new question as separate question instead of having it in comments.